# Cancel asyncio task upon reaching certain condition

Tags: python, python-asyncio

How can I properly close asyncio infinite loop task upon reaching certain condition? Let's say I want to cancel infinite loop if the number in function reaches 20:

```
import asyncio

async def main(numb):
    if numb == 20:
        print('Reached')
        get_loop = asyncio.get_running_loop()
        get_loop.stop()

    print(numb)

async def create_tasks():
    numb = 0 

    while True:
        x = asyncio.create_task(main(numb))
        
        numb += 1
        await x

asyncio.run(create_tasks())
```

Is there more proper way to do it? If I do not cancel the task asyncio way and just use "return" instead, the event loop gets hung and never prints that the script finished to the stdout.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the code as it is there, just raise an exception on `main`, it will be re-raised at the `await` point.

```py
import asyncio

class StopTasks(Exception):
    pass

async def main(numb):
    if numb == 20:
        raise StopTasks()

    print(numb)

async def create_tasks():
    numb = 0 

    while True:
        x = asyncio.create_task(main(numb))
        
        numb += 1
        try:
            await x
        except StopTasks:
            break

asyncio.run(create_tasks())
```

If you are running tasks in parallel, though there are other ways to go -
probably you are better using [asyncio.wait](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-task.html#asyncio.wait) and cancel the pending tasks - in that case you have to use a global variable to communicate that you are done - (it could also be an exception)